# AuthenticationException thrown in AuthenticationProvider is mapped to AccessDeniedException in ExceptionTranslationFilter

Tags: spring, spring-security

Having written a custom AuthenticationProvider (which calls a service, after which that one calls an external URL to authenticate the given credentials), I wanted to customize the error message people get when their authentication fails, based on the message I pass to the instance of AuthenticationException (so the `e.getMessage()` passed to `BadCredentialsExceptoin` in the code below).

```java
@Component
public class TapasAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public TapasAuthentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String userName = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        try {
            AuthenticationResponse authResponse = authenticationService.authenticate(userName, password);
            return new TapasAuthentication(mapToAuthenticatedUser(authResponse, userName, password), password);
        } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
            // Note that AuthenticationFailedException is a self-written exception, thrown by the authenticationService.
            log.error("Authentication failed: ", e);
            throw new BadCredentialsException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Now I looked up how to map `AuthenticationException`s and found that an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` should be used for this. So I created one and added it to my SecuritySetup:

```java
@Component
public class TapasAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(authException.getMessage());
        // More code to be added once exception is what I expect.
    }

}
```

```java
    @Autowired
    private TapasAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

This successfully triggers the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, but instead of a `BadCredentialsException`, I get an `InsufficientAuthenticationException`. I checked the origin of this exception and it comes from the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`'s handleSpringSecurityException. Here the exception turns out to be an `AccessDeniedException` instead of an `AuthenticationException`.

```java
    private void handleSpringSecurityException(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, RuntimeException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            // I would except to enter this if-statement, but exception is not what I expect
            sendStartAuthentication(request, response, chain,
                    (AuthenticationException) exception);
        }
        else if (exception instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
            ....
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) || authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication)) {
                // Instead code comes here, and creates an InsufficientAuthenticationException.

                sendStartAuthentication(
                        request,
                        response,
                        chain,
                        new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                            messages.getMessage(
                                "ExceptionTranslationFilter.insufficientAuthentication",
                                "Full authentication is required to access this resource")));
            }
            ...
        }
    }
```

Why does the exception not match my exception thrown in the `AuthenticationProvider`? And how would I be able to pass data from the `AuthenticationProvider` back to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the `HttpBasicConfigurer` returned by the `.basicSecurity()` call also allows to register an `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. When registering it that way, the exception thrown by the Provider does end up in the entry point.

Security config looks like this:

```java
    @Autowired
    private TapasAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```